# PHP - How to Highlight all word (utf-8) match

Tags: php

I try to highlight all word match like

Example: input is `đã` then all word will be highlight are `đã đÃ ĐÃ Đã`

But only `đã` is highlight.

[image]

Here is my full code

```
<?php
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' );

function highlightWords($text, $words) {
    $text = preg_replace("|($words)|Ui", "<span class=\"highlight_word\">$1</span>", $text);
    return $text;
}
$string = 'đã đÃ ĐÃ Đã';
$words = 'đã';
$string =  highlightWords($string, $words);
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>PHPRO Highlight Search Words</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
.highlight_word{
        background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <?php echo $string; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

How to Highlight all word (utf-8) match (like example) thanks.

Comment: Why you want to use PHP and not Javascript ?

Comment: @S.Visser I follow some tutorial and that's using php :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are only seeing the first highlighted is because you are using `U` (PCRE_UNGREEDY) modifier, and I think this is the reason for confusion.  I'm assuming you meant to use the `u` (PCRE_UTF8) modifier, which would treat the pattern string(s) as `UTF-8`.  Please see the various "[Pattern Modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)" for details.

Try using `u (PCRE_UTF8)` in your `preg_replace` function as follows and you should see all the words highlighted:

```
function highlightWords($text, $words) {
    $text = preg_replace("|($words)|ui", "<span class=\"highlight_word\">$1</span>", $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Here is the [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/bmh-u3i) of this.

Comment: If I try `$words = 'da';`, it does not work :( How to fix that? `da` should be highlighted as well.

Comment: If I try `$string = 'đã đÃ ĐÃ Đã da dá';
$words = 'da';`, it does not work :( because they're not all highlighted. Only `da` is highlighted. How to fix that? `dá` should be highlighted as well.